# Make pop-up or dialog window with list of photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make dialog/pop-up window with list of photos(currently I`m trying to so it with smartPhoto.js, but there is some issues). That photos should become bigger, when clicking on that.

Do you have any ideas how to implement that? Any help appreciates

Comment: You could use a modal to display a bigger version of the clicked image. let's say you have your list full of photos, then you click one and the modal displays the "full size" photo

Answer (score 0):

start off with a placeholder div inside a new page window.

style the div so it has display:none, and takes up most of the screen. you can even give it a transparent black background, and you can say that when you click on a link or a thumbnail, that div will appear and you can put your photo with javascript through the onclick event on that div.

make sure you change the z-index of the div aswell.

finally since this is all happening inside a popup window, you just need a link with target=_blank to display the contents of your page in a popup.